# How to suppress $WSEP header in Websphere Liberty Core 17.0.0.1

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

I have an application running on the Websphere Liberty Core 17.0.0.1. Whenever it responds with 4xx status code web container adds header named `$WSEP` to the response. For example:

```
$WSEP →
Cache-Control →no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Language →en-US
Content-Type →text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date →Tue, 30 May 2017 13:21:21 GMT
Expires →0
Pragma →no-cache
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
```

I tried to add web container property `suppressErrorPageODRHeader` into my `server.xml` do suppress this header, however it doesn't work.

```
<webContainer suppressErrorPageODRHeader="true"/>
```

How can I configure my web container to suppress this header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the full webcontainer name "com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.suppresserrorpageodrheader" and that should suppress $WSEP header.

Some of the original/old WAS properties do not have shortname in Liberty.

Answer (score 1):

```
<webContainer com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.suppresserrorpageodrheader="true"/>
```